# Generate blob upload URL from Blob Key googleblobstore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

I am trying to upload blob to google blob store I am using this method to get upload Key

```
BlobKey key = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/saad");
```

I wonder how to create upload URL from this key ?

I know that i can get URL directly using the line bellow

```
String blobUploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/saad");
```

but in this case I can't get the blob key which I need to store in my database in order to be able to download the file later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. You don't create a `BlobKey` first, you retrieve the key after uploading.

So you will:

1- Create an upload URL:

`String blobUploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/saad");`

2- Upload to the URL (POST from your app/form).

3- After the upload, `/saad` will be called automatically. You should have a POST handler mapped to `/saad`. From there, you retrieve the blobs uploaded from the `HttpServletRequest` object using `blobstoreService.getBlobInfos(request)` or `blobstoreService.getUploads(request)`.

See [Uploading a blob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob) for more info.